# Open outlook template file using C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have small application that needs to be able to open an already created outlook template file. On a side not I can easily open a blank outlook email. However, everything I have tried so far does not seem to work.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;

private void CreateItemFromTemplate()
        {
            Outlook.Folder folder =
                Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
                Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts) as Outlook.Folder;
            Outlook.MailItem mail =
                Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(
                @"Forms\\RLA.oft", folder) as Outlook.MailItem;
            mail.Subject = "Congratulations";
            mail.Save();
        }
```

This came directly from a MS site, but I get errors under Session and CreateItemFromTemplate. I have tried including all recommended references, but nothing works.

Here is another option I have tried.

```
           OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
          //MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\Content\\RLW.oft", OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

This option just above will work with the CreateItem object, but not with the CreateItemFromTemplate object.

It can't be this difficult for C# to open a template. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there an error or does it just return `null`?

Comment: We can't open '..\Content\RLW.oft'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.

To check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: We can't open '..\Content\RLW.oft'.It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.

Comment: That's the error that comes up. I've followed these instructions. gone to properties. No way to choose permissions. Plus, I have scripts, pics, other files that don't do this, or need permission. why does this one?

Comment: the parent directory designator (..) in the exception message is at odds with the root directory path you pass to the function. would it work if you passed it the absolute path to the template file?

Comment: Is the file already open? Is it already open in Outlook?   Could it be open by a previously failed attempt with your program (i.e. reboot and try again)

Comment: So I tried some directly from my C drive.                                              MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("c:\\RLW.oft", OlItemType.olMailItem);   It came up with this error.Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again.  Weird right?

Comment: It's not open. I've closed outlook completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any comes across this later, I figured my own answer out. This line right here is the problem.

```
MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\Content\\RLW.oft", OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

Visual Studio actually tells you when hovering over this when writing it. The parameter "OlItemType.olMailItem" is the folder it looks in. If you leave that parameter out it will look in the given pathway. If not, it won't open correctly.